# Large File Processing in WSO2 ESB with headers and trailer

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a big file (say 100K records) with header and trailer. Trailer contains information regarding number of records in this file. is there any way for WSO2 ESB to load this entire file for processing (say reading each row and perform some validation and than sending validated data to external end point) and validate number of records is matching against data present in trailer ?